# How to free a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, free

I have created a linked list in a function and throughout the rest of the program I am accessing the list using a pointer. Now how would I free this linked list at the end of my program? Do I plainly use `free(CircuitData)` or do I have to run through the list freeing each node? Writing this I'm thinking freeing each node is the obvious answer...

On a side note I'd also like to ask how to find out whether all memory allocated during a program is freed properly?

```
 ListNodeType *CircuitData;
 CircuitData = NULL;
 ReadFile(&CircuitData, &numEl, &numNodes);


void ReadFile(ListNodeType **CircuitData, int *numEl, int *numNodes){

    ListNodeType *newPtr, *tempPtr;
    newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNodeType));
    *CircuitData = newPtr;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    //MORE CODE
```

Comment: For your first question, based on you fragment of an allocation, free each node. In reality it is dependent on how the list is allocated (obviously). Some link-lists are done in a static buffer, but yours certainly appears to follow the rule and not the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every `malloc` you will need a `free` otherwise you will leak memory. One possible way to analyze your program to see if you don't have memory leaks is to use [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

Answer (score 7):

I would think of something like this:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    node* next;
} *head;

void deleteAllNodes(node* start)
{
    while (start != NULL)
    { 
        node* temp = start; 
        start = start -> next;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: delete is a c++ construct, not c

Comment: Doesn't free have to go after we proceed to the next item?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like this :

```
void freeFunction(ListNodeType *CircuitData)
{
    void *victim;

    while (CircuitData)
    {
        victim = CircuitData;
        CircuitData = CircuitData->next;
        free(victim);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is accurate, though you don't need `tmp`. Just walk with `CircuitData`. there is no reason to retain its original value as you're destroying everything it ever points to anyway. And the last if-clause isn't needed if done correctly.

Comment: That's right `tmp` is useless but I put it only for understanding ;)

Comment: As written it will double-free() the last node, and worse, free() an indeterminate (read:invalid) pointer if the passed in list is empty. that last `if` block shouldn't be there at all. **Edit:** had to fix it, it was wrong, and for some reason receiving up-votes regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried that and then after I called the function I tried printing an element of CircuitData and it still printed a previous value. Shouldn't it have printed gibberish?

Comment: @Andre even accessing that element once the pointer is freed is undefined behavior. That is still has some/most of the data in memory is simply how the library `free()` manages it. In most cases, a library `free()` simply adds the block back in to the free-list and allows it to become available for future allocation.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, yes, you should walk the list and `free` each node.

The second question is a bit harder to answer. If you have an object in memory, but no way to access it, that's a memory leak.

There are tools you can use to analyze your memory pool. Check out valgrind:

http://valgrind.org/